# Linq expression not supported

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have the following LINQ to Entities expression:

```
var allItemsOver64 =
  _inventoryContext.Items.Where(
  i => DateTimeHelper.CalculateAgeInYears(i.PrimaryInsured.DoB, now) >= 65);
```

The problem is that when I use allItemsOver64 it says that this expression is not supported.  I have a feeling that this error is happening because of the call to the CalculateAgeInYears method.  Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Thanks,

Sachin

Edit:

Even after changing the code to use IEnumerables I still get the same error.  Here is my code now:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var allItemsOver64 =
                _inventoryContext.Items.Where(
                    i => DateTimeHelper.CalculateAgeInYears(i.PrimaryInsured.DoB, now) >= 65).AsEnumerable();
            IEnumerable<Item> items65To69 = allItemsOver64.Where(
                i =>
                DateTimeHelper.CalculateAgeInYears(i.PrimaryInsured.DoB, now) >= 65 &&
                DateTimeHelper.CalculateAgeInYears(i.PrimaryInsured.DoB, now) <= 69).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: So it works with `<=65`?

Comment: I don't need any items for ages less than 65 so that doesn't even come into the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I infer correctly from your functions name, I think this may be what you're looking for:

```
using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;

var allItemsOver64 = _inventoryContext
                     .Items
                     .Where(i => (SqlFunctions
                                  .DateDiff("dd", i.PrimaryInsured.DoB, now) / 365.0) 
                                  >= 65.0);
```

Comment: You're on the right track, but you will be off by a year until the person's birth date passes **this** year.

Comment: @Sachin I'm sorry don't see you using `SqlFuntions` in your code.

Comment: Ah no, I see, I didn't actually have SqlFunctions.  But as Yuck says this won't work.

Comment: According to Yuck: "you will be off by a year until the person's birth date passes this year".

Comment: I'm going to try this approach.

Comment: The expression ((((Convert(DateDiff("dd", [10007].PrimaryInsured.DoB, 26/04/2012 15:03:09)) / 365) >= 65) And ((Convert(DateDiff("dd", [10007].PrimaryInsured.DoB, 26/04/2012 15:03:09)) / 365) >= 65)) And ((Convert(DateDiff("dd", [10007].PrimaryInsured.DoB, 26/04/2012 15:03:09)) / 365) <= 69)) is not supported.

Answer (score 5):

You can't call C# methods in EF queries, because EF doesn't know how to turn the method into SQL.

Instead, call `.AsEnumerable()` first to force the `Where()` to run locally.

Comment: That will work...but what if the set includes millions of records? That would need all records to be retrieved to the client first. Then the function gets called for each item in memory. It could really kill performance.

Answer (score 2):

Because Linq cannot interpret your helper method to SQL command. You should implement such logic on db side, or select all values and only then make check on client side. Neither of it is pretty for me, that's why I always try to simplify DB, to make as simple queries as it's possible.

Comment: how do I implement this logic at the db side?

Comment: for example add function and select result of it in query, or add view, which will select one of fields already calculated by your helper. There are dozens of ways, but try to avoid it, it really makes finding bugs complex, on the other way selecting everything to client makes query results huge and hurt perfomance.

Comment: Hi Johnny, I'm trying the client side approach by making the result an IEnumerable (see edit above) but I still get exactly the same error.  Why is this?

Comment: @SachinKainth, you have to make AsEnumerable or ToList first, to make ORM get data from db, and then apply where with your function. Currently you are making it vice versa.